# How to reduce this differential equation into first-order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

How can we reduce this differential equation into first-order differential equation?

> > $\left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U \left( z \right)  \right) ^{3}{
> > \frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{z}^{2}}}U \left( z \right) + \left( {
> > \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U \left( z \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{4
> > }}{{\rm d}{z}^{4}}}U \left( z \right) - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
> > {\rm d}{z}^{2}}}U \left( z \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{
> > {\rm d}{z}^{3}}}U \left( z \right) =0
> > $

Comment: You should specify what techniques have you tried or do you think should work. You must put more context on you starting point

Comment: I tried it by integration, i.e. ${\frac { \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U \left( z \right)  \right) ^
{4}}{4}}- \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{z}^{2}}}U \left( z
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U \left( z
 \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{z}^{3}}}U \left( z
 \right) -{\it C1}=0$, where $C1$ is the constant of integration. But I am not clear whether it works further or not.

Answer (score 1):

Set $V=U'$, then
$$
V^3V'+VV'''-V'V''=0.
$$
The last two terms look like the numerator of a quotient derivative
$$
VV'+\left(\frac{V''}{V}\right)'=0
$$
Set $W=\frac12V^2+\frac{V''}{V}$, then $W'=0$ and
$$
V''+\frac12V^3=VW
$$
So if the components of the state vector are $X=[U,V,V',W]^T$, then
$$
X'=[V,V', VW-\frac12V^3,0]^T,
$$
that is
$$
X'=\pmatrix{X_1'\\X_2'\\X_3'\\X_4'}
=F(x)=\pmatrix{X_2\\X_3\\X_2X_4-X_2^3/2\\0}
$$
Compared to the simpler first order system using the derivatives vector to $U$, this requires a non-trivial transformation of the initial value for $W(z_0)$. The advantage here is that the right side has no divisions by variable expressions. One could also eliminate $W$ as component and just use it as constant (depending on the initial value), thus reducing the dimension of the system.

Comment: I can't understand the state vector $X$. The final equation is the first-order differential in $X$?

Comment: Yes, I replaced $\frac{d}{dz}$ by the prime.

Comment: when I substitute back and write an equation for $U$. The result is of 2nd-order DE, i.e., ${\frac { \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{z}^{2}}}U \left( z
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}+{\frac { \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U
 \left( z \right)  \right) ^{4}}{8}}-{\frac {c \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}z}}U \left( z \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}={\it C2}$, $C2$ is constant.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, this is another constant of motion/first integral. It's usefulness is slightly in doubt for numerical integration, especially when the integration should go over sign changes of $U''$.

Comment: I tries to solve ${\frac { \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{z}^{2}}}U \left( z
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}+{\frac { \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}U
 \left( z \right)  \right) ^{4}}{8}}-{\frac {c \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}z}}U \left( z \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}={\it C2}
$ by integration, but I could not reduce this 2nd-order DE to 1st-order DE. How to do that?

Comment: There might be "named" special functions, solutions of normalized second-order, but that will not be overly helpful. It is only a very thin set of ODE that have a symbolic solution.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by Lutz Lehmann,
\begin{align}
\frac{(U')^2}{2}+\frac{U'''}{U'}=C_1,
\end{align}
Multiplying by $U'U''$ and integrating
\begin{align}
\frac{(U')^4}{8}+\frac{(U'')^2}{2}=C_1\frac{(U')^2}{2}+C_2^2,\\\\
2U''=\sqrt{(U')^4+2C_1(U')^2+C_2^2},
\end{align}
which is separable
\begin{align}
\int \frac{2 \mathrm dU'}{\sqrt{-(U')^4+2C_1(U')^2+C_2^2}}+C_3\equiv \mathcal I(U')=z,
\end{align}
which is the first order differential equation you requested. $\mathcal I$ involves the elliptic integral of the first kind, [here's a link to WA's solution.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%202%2Fsqrt%28-x%5E4%2B2c_1%20x%5E2%2Bc_2%29%20dx)

The solution to equations of the form $z=\mathcal I(U')$ can be found via the method of integration by differentiation. Denote $U'=\xi$, where $\xi$ will be our parameter in the parametric solution. Taking a derivative of our first order differential equation, substituting in our relation for $\xi$, and integrating we find the solution to be
\begin{align}
U(\xi)=\int \xi \mathcal I'(\xi)\mathrm d\xi+C_4,\quad z(\xi)=\mathcal I(\xi).
\end{align}

The integral for $U(\xi)$ comes out as

\begin{align}
U(\xi)-C_4=-\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{C_1-\xi^2}{\sqrt{-\xi^4+2C_1\xi^2+C_2^2}}\right)\longrightarrow
\xi=\pm\sqrt{C_1+ C_2\sin(U+C_4)},
\end{align}
So then our parametric solution can be reduced to an implicit one if we desire (which is not usually the case with this method)
\begin{align}
z=\mathcal I\left(\pm\sqrt{C_1+C_2\sin(U+C_4)}\right), \quad\text{where}\quad \mathcal I(s)=\int\frac{2 \mathrm ds}{\sqrt{-s^4+2C_1 s^2+C_2^2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: I am trying to find the P.E of the system which is $(U^{'})^{2}+V(U)=constant$. I am not clear on how to do it from first order D.E which contains the elliptic integral.

Comment: Does this equation model a physical system? Why do you think the equation should reduce to that form?

Comment: I don't know whether the equation model a physical system. But I am trying to do it by finding U(z), which is potential of the system. In my last comment, V(U) should be U(z)

Comment: I see. The answer you’re looking for is shown in my second to last equation involving $\xi$. Can you spot what I’m talking about?

Comment: from $U^{'}=\xi=\pm\sqrt{C_{1}+C_{2}\sin(U+C_{4})}$ one can get the potential of the system?

Comment: Try rearranging that equation. Do you see how you could get $(U’)^2+V(U)=\dots$ ?

Comment: how did you solve the integral for $U(\xi)$? By symbolic computation? Can you share the link or code of this solution?

Comment: I use Wolfram Alpha and integral-calculator.com